# Improve my Unzip & Move function - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3, zip, unzip

I'm a PHP novice and so looking for some advice on a PHP function i have created to use within a Wordpress installation.

As you can see from the code below, it runs when one of the admin's press 'Publish' on a pending post.

It takes a Zip file that has been uploaded by a user via Gravity Forms, then unzips ONLY .mp3 extensions. Re-zips and moves all the files to a new folder in our Amazon S3 directory.

The code is pieced together from my limited knowledge and some help along the way with questions on here.

So, here's what i ended up with:

```
    add_action('pending_to_publish', 'unzip_to_s3');  
   function unzip_to_s3() { 
   global $post;
   global $wpdb;

   // Only run function if post is portfolio post type
    if ('portfolio' == $post->post_type) {

   // Set temp path
   $temp_path = '../wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-9e5dc27086c8b2fd2e48678e1f54f98c/2013/02/tmp/';

   // Get filename from Zip file
   $file = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'file_url', true);
   $zip_file = basename($file);

   // Create full Zip file path
   $zip_file_path = $temp_path.$zip_file;

   // Generate unique name for temp sub_folder for unzipped files
   $temp_unzip_folder = uniqid('temp_TMS_', true);

   // Create full temp sub_folder path
   $temp_unzip_path = $temp_path.$temp_unzip_folder;

   // Make the new temp sub_folder for unzipped files
   if (!mkdir($temp_unzip_path, 0755, true)) {
    die('Error: Could not create path: '.$temp_unzip_path);
   }

   // Unzip files to temp unzip folder, ignoring anything that is not a .mp3 extension
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $filename = $zip_file_path;

   if ($zip->open($filename)!==TRUE) {
      exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
   }

   for ($i=0; $i<$zip->numFiles;$i++) {
      $info = $zip->statIndex($i);
      $file = pathinfo($info['name']);
      if(strtolower($file['extension']) == "mp3") {
           file_put_contents($temp_unzip_path.'/'.basename($info['name']), $zip->getFromIndex($i));
      } else {
      $zip->deleteIndex($i);
      }
   }
   $zip->close();

   // Re-zip the unzipped mp3's and store new zip file in temp folder created earlier
   $temp_unzip_path = $temp_unzip_path.'/';
   $zip = new ZipArchive();
   $dirArray = array();
   $new_zip_file = $temp_unzip_path.$zip_file;

   $new = $zip->open($new_zip_file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
   if ($new === true) {
       $handle = opendir($temp_unzip_path);
       while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
           if(!in_array($entry,array('.','..')))
           {
               $dirArray[] = $entry;
               $zip->addFile($temp_unzip_path.$entry,$entry);
           }
       }
       closedir($handle);
   } else {
       echo 'Failed to create Zip';
   }

   $zip->close();

   // Set Media bucket dir
   $bucket_path = '../wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-9e5dc27086c8b2fd2e48678e1f54f98c/2013/02/mixtape2/';

   // Generate unique name for sub_bucket
   $sub_bucket = uniqid('TMS_', true);

   // Create full sub_bucket path
   $sub_bucket_path = $bucket_path.$sub_bucket;

   // Make the new sub_bucket
   if (!mkdir($sub_bucket_path, 0755, true)) {
    die('Error: Could not create path: '.$sub_bucket_path);
   }

   // Move mp3's to new sub_bucket 
   // Get array of all source files
   $files = scandir($temp_unzip_path);
   // Identify directories
   $source = $temp_unzip_path;
   $destination = $sub_bucket_path.'/';
   // Cycle through all source files
   foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
        // if move files is successful delete the original temp folder
        if (rename($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
            rmdir($temp_unzip_path);
        }
    }

   // Delete original Zip file
   unlink($temp_path.$zip_file);

   // Update Custom field for new Zip file location
   update_post_meta($post->ID, 'file_url', 'http://themixtapesite.com/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/1-9e5dc27086c8b2fd2e48678e1f54f98c/2013/02/mixtape2/'.$sub_bucket.'/'.$zip_file);

   }
   }
```

Whilst this function does work, we're dealing with large files and so it does take a while to process...
What is happening is when the admin presses publish it triggers this function but the page just sits there until it's finished this function and then will continue. This function can take upto around 5 minutes to run.

I'm looking to optimise this function (in terms of code) but also see if there's a way i can run this in the background so that the admin can carry on with other things and not have to sit there waiting around.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds more like a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: didn't even know that existed... thanks, i'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to WP cron and schedule the task at that point so that it runs in the background.  Here is some resources for that.  the basic concept would go something like this.

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'pending_to_publish' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_single_event($timestamp,'pending_to_publish');
}

add_action('pending_to_publish', 'unzip_to_s3');
```

http://wpengineer.com/1908/use-wordpress-cron/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category%3aWP-Cron_Functions

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/run-a-cron-job-or-similar-in-the-background-of-wp-after-post-update-create